# Unproved identity for computing $\zeta (s)$ at negative odd integers

Tags: analysis, riemann-zeta

I stumbled upon this interesting identity, but I cannot find the proof of it:
$$\zeta (-s)=\int_{-1}^0\sum_{k=1}^n k^s \mathrm dn ,\, s=2r+1,\, r\in\mathbb N_0 .$$
For example, setting $s=1$ yields $\zeta (-1)=\int_{-1}^0 \frac{n^2+n}{2}\, \mathrm dn =-\frac{1}{12}$.
Is the formula for general negative odd integers true? If yes, can someone refer me to the proof?

Comment: The zeta function is not defined at $x_0=-1$. The $-1/12$ is a hypothetical value.

Comment: @Peter The Riemann-Zeta function is defined for all $s\in\mathbb{C}\setminus1$ by analytic continuation.

Comment: Your finite sum is a power sum, which can be expressed in terms of the Bernoulli numbers, and since there is a closed form for $\zeta(s)$ in terms of the Bernoulli numbers for odd argument, then it's no surprise that the formula gives what you find. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Specific_values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^0\sum_{k=1}^nk^s\mathrm{d}n
&=\int_{-1}^0\frac1{s+1}\sum_{j=0}^s\binom{s+1}{j}B_j^+n^{s+1-j}\mathrm{d}n\\
&=\frac1{s+1}\sum_{j=0}^s\binom{s+1}{j}B_j^+\int_{-1}^0n^{s+1-j}\mathrm{d}n\\
&=\frac1{s+1}\sum_{j=0}^s\binom{s+1}{j}B_j^+\left[\frac{n^{s+2-j}}{s+2-j}\right]_{-1}^0\\
&=\frac1{s+1}\sum_{j=0}^s\binom{s+1}{j}B_j^+\frac{(-1)^{s+1-j}}{s+2-j}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{s+1}}{s+1}\sum_{j=0}^s\binom{s+1}{j}B_j^+\frac{(-1)^{j}}{s+2-j}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{s+1}}{s+1}\sum_{j=0}^s\binom{s+1}{j}\frac{B_j^-}{s+2-j}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{s+1}}{s+1}(-B_{s+1}^-)\\
&=-\frac{B_{s+1}^+}{s+1}\\
&=\zeta(-s)\\
\end{align}